# Check if boost is used in a binary

Tags: c++, boost, dylib

I'm having problems writing a plugin as a dylib for a poorly documented application on osx and I'm wondering if its because of a missmatch in boost libraries used in my .dylib and the application. Does anybody know of any way to check if boost was used and if so what version?

Its a long shot I know

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$ nm some.dylib | grep boost
```

but I'm in doubt that you'll find an exact version...